# Silly question about black hole analogues: is it possible do construct an "at home-DIY" experiment?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, black-holes, experimental-physics, home-experiment

First of all, to the fellow Physics Stack Exchange community:

1. I'm a undergraduate student with knowledge on basic General Relativity (GR).
2. I do not asking this with an aim to extract relevant competitive results.
3. I have a poor knowledge on black hole analogues concerning the theory and experimental theory; I know actually, just the basic intuitive idea about this branch of GR.

> So, in the spirit of DIY projects and concerning the experimental set of a [dumb hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_black_hole), is it possible to construct an black hole analogue experiment, and measure something, even barely?

$$ * * * $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way to make an analogue black hole would be with water flow tabletop experiments.

As was noticed by Schützhold & Unruh propagation of gravity waves could be described by an analogue metric:

- Schützhold, R., & Unruh, W. G. (2002). *Gravity wave analogues of black holes.* Physical Review D, 66(4), 044019, [doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.66.044019](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.66.044019), [arXiv:gr-qc/0205099](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0205099).

There has been several projects for such fluid analogue black holes [see this example](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4767) [or this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.08473) with rather impressive looking setups, with the most simple being [this student project](http://physics.wooster.edu/REU/Manz/BlackHole.html) with this 2m x 1m water tank:

[image: image from poster by Marc Manheim, Lindner & Niklas Manz]

Here is quite recent overview of hydrodynamic analogue models and  designs of experiments:

- Rousseaux, G., & Kellay, H. (2020). *Classical Hydrodynamics for Analogue Spacetimes: Open Channel Flows and Thin Films*. [arXiv:2005.03301](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03301).

This paper also describes a potentially even simpler experiment: propagation of capillary waves in flowing sheets of soap:

[image: image from Rousseaux & Kellay]