# Examples of black hole analogues

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, experimental-physics

After spending some time looking for different means and mediums to model blackholes, I came across [sonic holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_black_hole) which are modeled through Bose-Einstein-Condensates.
However I have not been able to find any other possible methods of modeling blackholes (other than computer simulations). [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562464/silly-question-about-black-hole-analogues-is-it-possible-do-construct-an-at-ho) addresses the issue only partially.
Are there any other proposed or experimentally tested methods of modeling blackholes?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the setup with BECs in optical traps, probably the most well known setup for an analogue of black hole is in a [wave tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_tank), see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1911). By judiciously varying the depth of the tank (which affects the propagation speed of waves), you can setup a situation where at some point in the tank the flow rate of the water is larger than the propagation speed of the waves. This creates a sonic horizon.

Of course, such a setup is very far from the quantum regime. Nonetheless, according to the same paper, you can observe a classical analogue of Hawking radiation involving [stimulated emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission).